# Find a document that contains a specific value in an array, or exists in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here I have two Documents, I need to find if the array exists with `"admin"`, Which is the best way `$in` or `$exists`?

```
{
    "url_name" : "List All Active clients",
    "org_url" : "localhost:4523/create_project/active_clients_list",
    "site_url" : "create_project/active_clients_list",
    "roles" : {
        "writer" : [ 
            "get", 
            "post", 
            "put"
        ],
        "admin" : [ 
            "get", 
            "post", 
            "put"
        ]
    },
    "updated_on" : ISODate("2018-08-21T05:09:25.896Z"),
    "created_on" : ISODate("2018-08-21T05:09:25.896Z")
}, {
    "url_name" : "List All Active clients",
    "org_url" : "localhost:4523/create_project/active_clients_list",
    "site_url" : "create_project/active_clients_list",
    "roles" : {
        "writer" : [ 
            "get", 
            "post", 
            "put"
        ]
    },
    "updated_on" : ISODate("2018-08-21T05:09:34.407Z"),
    "created_on" : ISODate("2018-08-21T05:09:34.407Z")                    
}
```

Consider the two document and i need to find the document where `"admin"` exists

Comment: You cannot find documents using `$in` here... `$exists` is only the way... `db.collection.find({
  "roles.admin": {
    "$exists": true
  }
})`

Answer (score 0):

Use the mongoDB [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) query operator:

```
db.collection.find({ "roles.admin": { "$exists": true } })
```

**Syntax:**

```
{ field: { $exists: <boolean> } }
```